# Rectangular form to polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When asked to convert the rectangular form of the complex number $\sin\theta + i\cos\theta$ to polar form, I always get $\operatorname{cis} [(90 - \theta)/ \theta)]$ instead of the correct answer which is $\operatorname{cis}(90 - \theta)$. How can I get the right answer?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck - without seeing your working out how can we tell where you went wrong? This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: The way you say "when asked..." means probably that your interlocutor is a computer with a certain software. Can you say a little more about it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Polar Transformation** means:
$$
(a, b) \longrightarrow (\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \tan^{-1} (ba^{-1}))
$$

There is another representation for complex numbers:
$$
a + bi = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot e^{i\tan^{-1} (ba^{-1})}
$$

Similarly,
$$
\sin{\theta} + i\cos{\theta} = \sqrt{\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}} e^{i\tan^{-1} (\cos{\theta}(\sin{\theta})^{-1})} = e^{i\tan^{-1} (\cot{\theta})} = e^{i\tan^{-1} (\tan{\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta})} = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)}
$$

In your notation:
$$
\text{cis} \theta = e^{i\theta}
$$

Hence,
$$
\sin{\theta} + i\cos{\theta} = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)} = \text{cis}(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)
$$

I hope that answers your question!